# Format SQL query result using PHP to display horizontally

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display my query in the format shown

```
    Size Group  Year1   Year2  Year 3   Year 4
    Small       data     data   data     data (this row data are related to small associated with each year)
    Med         data     data   data     data (this row data are related to Med associated with each year)
    Large       data     data   data     data (this row data are related to Large associated with each year)
```

I'm able to display the data vertically, but I have no idea how to display the data horizontally, year 1, 2,3,4 continues onward

I have the following code that displays the data vertically
HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">year</th>
        <th scope="col">small</th>
        <th scope="col">medium</th>
        <th scope="col">large</th>
        <th scope="col">extra large</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php table($conn) ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>" . "<td>$row[yr]</td>" . "<td>$row[small]</td>" . "<td>$row[medium]</td>" . "<td>$row[large]</td>". "<td>$row[extralarge]</td>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Fail to query ";
}
```

The output of this code:

```
Year Small Medium Large ExtraLarge
2001  12    13     14    15    
2002  12    13     14    15    
2003  12    13     14    15
```

Desire display, year display horizontally dynamically

```
Size Group    2001 2002 2003
Small          12   12  12
Medium         13   13  13
Large          14   14  14
Extralarge     15   15  15
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the data you are starting with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simulate my understanding of your question here. You can try this. Hope this helps you :)

```
 CREATE TABLE size_group_data_by_year( year int, small int, medium int, large int, extralarge int);

INSERT INTO size_group_data_by_year VALUES 
(2001,  12,    13,     14,    15),   
(2002,  12,    13,     14,    15),  
(2003,  12,    13,     14,    15);

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + '[' + CAST(year AS VARCHAR) +']'  FROM size_group_data_by_year
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM size_group_data_by_year;

SET @sql = 'SELECT size_group,'+ @columns + 'FROM
(
SELECT year, size_group, data
FROM size_group_data_by_year
UNPIVOT (
     data FOR size_group IN (
        [small],[medium],[large],[extralarge]
    )
) unpvt
) AS src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(data) FOR year IN ('+@columns+')
) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can find this simulation here: https://rextester.com/ZALB59809

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I have a query generated already, I'm trying to use the result and format the output

Comment: @YeLuWang: I guess you are trying to do too much transformations in php, and so I thought it would be better if you do the transformations in SQL and just display the output in php :)

Comment: Just to clarify, this will only work in SQL Server. If OP is using another database, e.g mySQL for example, then different syntax would be needed. I like the concept though

Comment: Yes. This was written in SQL server syntax. should change to any other syntax if specified/needed by OP :).